# How to Buy an Apartment in Germany living on the blue card

Tags: germany, housing, financial

I would like to buy an apartment in Germany, and I live on the blue card.

How can I do it? If not possible now, when  will it be? What is the procedure?

Comment: "How can I do it?": I would start by talking to a real estate agent *(Immobilienmakler?).*  They probably know the answers to all of these questions.

Comment: It's possible and you follow the same procedure as anyone else, including German citizens. There are no legal restrictions. If you don't speak German you need a translator, that's about it.

Comment: You will have difficulty getting a loan if you don't have a permanent residence permit (Niederlassungserlaubnis).

Comment: Except the difficulty to get a loan from the bank if you need it, buying an apartment has nothing to do with Blue Card. AFAIK, **to buy** an apartment in Germany, you are even not required to be in Germany or have a German visa or residence permit. So what is your question then?

Comment: No question, I have no interest in buying an apartment in Germany anymore, and I did not see any issue in getting a loan, that was quite easy